# Having trouble figuring out regex to match these cases

Tags: regex

I have some different data formats I need to extract a token for, and I can't seem to get one of them.

```
Akhmim (former Panopolis)
Nishapur|Nishapur or Samarqand
probably Fustat
Northern India or Pakistan
India|Egypt
```

Above are the cases I need to be able to handle, and here is the regex I currently have:

```
(probably)?([A-Za-z ]+)
```

I need to be able to just capture the first token when multiple options are provided (either separated by | or "or"), and I can't figure out how to match just "Northern India" while keeping all of the other cases intact. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Do you have to do it with a single regexp? I suggest first searching for `|` or `or` and extracting the part before that, then getting the country from that.

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex should do what you want:

```
^(probably )?([A-Za-z ]+?)(?=\bor\b| ?\|| ?[^A-Za-z ]|$)
```

It looks for words, possibly preceded by `probably` and followed by either

- the word 'or'
- a `|` character, possibly preceded by a space
- a non-alphabetic character, possibly preceded by a space
- the end of line

Output for your sample data is:

```
Akhmim
Nishapur
probably Fustat
Northern India
India
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/eCFWZd/1/)

Answer (score 0):

try this pattern
(^[A-Za-z]+ ?([a-zA-Z]+)?)